# Fill perforated shape in image using python libs?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I have BW images with "perforation". The level of perforation can be different

[image][image][image][image]

Is there any "standard" ways to completely fill in the shapes with black to make them more similar?

Pillow & opencv preferred,  but imagemagick can works too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [image morphology(i.e: closing)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html) to achieve this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # read image
    image = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    # convert image to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # ensure only black and white pixels exist
    ret,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # morphology works with white forground
    binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

    # get kernel for morphology
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    # number of iterations depends on the type of image you're providing
    binary = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)

    # get black foreground
    binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

    cv2.imshow('image', binary)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: 1][image: 2]

[image: 3][image: 4]

Comment: why the inversion? couldn't you use opening instead of closing?

Comment: @filippo I could have, but I didn't want to confuse OP since he seems to be a beginner in OpenCV. This was a *closing* operation, so I used `cv2.MORPH_CLOSE`.